# Grails Database Migration plugin silently fails to add not null constraint

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, database-migration

I am trying to familiarize myself with the [Grails Database Migration Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) using [this site](http://wpgreenway.wordpress.com/2012/03/25/grails-db-migration-tutorial/) as a reference.  I have encountered a problem when trying to add a property with a not null constraint.  I modeled my script the same way as it is shown on the site (add the column, set defaults for existing records, then add a not nullable constraint to the column):

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(author: "Ryan (generated)", id: "1340893788251-1") {
        addColumn(tableName: "game") {
            column(name: "genre", type: "varchar(255)")
        }

        grailsChange{
            change{
                sql.executeUpdate("UPDATE game SET genre = 'Other'")
            }
        }

        addNotNullConstraint(tableName: "game", columnName: "genre")
    }
}
```

When I attempt to update my database it silently fails.  So, I split the three changes into three different groovy scripts to track down the problem.

First file (add column) worked fine:

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(author: "Ryan (generated)", id: "1340893788251-1") {
        addColumn(tableName: "game") {
            column(name: "genre", type: "varchar(255)")
        }
    }
}
```

Second file (assign default values to existing records) worked fine:

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(author: "Ryan (generated)", id: "defaultValue") {
        grailsChange{
            change{
                sql.executeUpdate("UPDATE game SET genre = 'Other'")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Third file (add not null constraint) silently fails:

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(author: "Ryan (generated)", id: "notNull") {
        addNotNullConstraint(tableName: "game", columnName: "genre")
    }
}
```

The log file only shows this in relation to the plugin:

> 2012-06-28 10:17:11,694 [main] INFO  liquibase  - Successfully acquired change log lock
>   2012-06-28 10:17:11,972 [main] INFO  liquibase  - Reading from `DATABASECHANGELOG`
>   2012-06-28 10:17:11,980 [main] INFO  liquibase  - Reading from `DATABASECHANGELOG`
>   2012-06-28 10:17:12,009 [main] INFO  liquibase  - Successfully released change log lock

If I check the databasechangelog table I can see that the script has not been executed.  The console gave me this:

> | Starting dbm-update for database root @ jdbc:mysql://localhost/migration

but there is no

> | Finished dbm-update

like I see with the successful updates.

**NOTE:** It may be important to note that the site I am using as a reference is using version 1.0, I am using version 1.1.  I am having a hard time finding tutorials or examples of this plugin at all, harder still to find info for the most recent version (released a month ago).

Can anyone pinpoint where I'm going wrong with the not null constraint?

Comment: It looks like this is a bug, since clearly the constraint isn't being applied. Do you know if the SQL that is being run actually fails or not?

Comment: To expand slightly on what cdexzaq said, do you encounter errors if you run `alter table game modify genre varchar(255) not null;` directly against your MySQL db?

Comment: @cdeszaq @proflux `alter table game modify genre varchar(255) not null;` probably would have worked.  I debugged the issue in a different way (see my answer below).

Comment: Ah! Sorry guys, I realized I had copied the wrong third file.  I updated the question.  The question and answer should make a little more sense now.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to ask about the `columnDataType` but I saw it listed in your changeset in the question.  That is a required attribute for `addNotNullConstraint` when using MySQL so seeing your updated 3rd file that makes much more sense why it was failing.

Comment: @proflux Ah, so it is specific to the database? MySQL (and probably some others) need `columnDataType` specified while other databases don't require it?

Comment: @Weezle - MySQL and MS-SQL require it.  http://www.liquibase.org/manual/add_not-null_constraint

Comment: Out of interest (I see you've already found the problem), does setting "failOnError: true" as an attribute of the changeset give any indication of the problem (rather than it just silently failing)?

Comment: @JonoB I wasn't even aware of that attribute.  Nope, nothing in the console, nothing in the log file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While at lunch I was thinking about this and wondered why I hadn't taken an obvious debugging step.  The groovy script changes were made from scratch.  The update to add the column worked, which means that the only difference between my DB and my domain object was the not nullable constraint:

```
class Game {
    String genre

    static constraints = {
        genre(nullable:  false, blank:  false)
    }
}
```

...so why not run `grails dbm-gorm-diff` and see what the plugin comes up with?

The result was this:

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(author: "Ryan (generated)", id: "1340897310305-1") {
        addNotNullConstraint(columnDataType: "varchar(255)", columnName: "genre", tableName: "game")
    }
}
```

The only difference between my created change script and the script that the plugin made was the:
columnDataType: "varchar(255)"

I added that to the script I made (just to be sure I hadn't done anything else wrong) and bingo, update worked.